# C++ How to typedef function with int parameter

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Define.h"
#include "AuthorativeGameClient.h"

class GameAuthorativeManager {
public:
    AuthorativeGameClient const * GetAuthorativeGameClientForMap(int map_id) const;

    static GameAuthorativeManager* instance();
};
#define sGameAuthrativeMgr GameAuthorativeManager::instance()
```

To access functions of `GameAuthorativeManager`, I do this:

```
sGameAuthrativeMgr->FUNCTION_NAME()
```

However, is there any way to reduce, just for sake of readability, something like this:

```
sGameAuthrativeMgr->GetAuthorativeGameClientForMap(12)->FUNCTION_NAME_HERE();
```

To something more like this:

```
aAuthClient(12)->->FUNCTION_NAME_HERE();
```

Comment: Create a short-cut function `AuthorativeGameClient const* aAuthClient(int map_id) { return sGameAuthrativeMgr->GetAuthorativeGameClientForMap(map_id); }`? Then invoke it as `aAuthClient(12)->FUNCTION_NAME_HERE();`

Comment: Why do you want to make such a thing? The syntax `->->` looks completely out of any standard

Comment: You class is a singleton. Add a static function which invokes instance().

Answer (score 1):

Yes? And it has nothing to do with typedefs. You can make a new function

```
AuthorativeGameClient const * aAuthClient(int map_id) {
    return sGameAuthrativeMgr->GetAuthorativeGameClientForMap(12);
}
```